# Blocked By Play Protect

Tags: android, google-play-protect

We have published our app in play store, and everything is ok. But when we send apk file via email the OS prevents installing it and shows this error:

[image]

Gradle default config:

```
compileSdkVersion 28
defaultConfig {
    applicationId 'app.package'
    minSdkVersion 17
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 21
    versionName "0.2.1"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
```

Permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
```

I think we have to submit our app via [this link](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/contact/protectappeals) but I read somewhere that the submission process takes 10-30 days.

Why the OS shows this error and how can we fix it?

Comment: Can you install it without problems via Play Store? Does this exclusively happen when installing it after downloading it from somewhere else?

Comment: @S. Czop  Yes we have published the app in play store and everything is ok

Comment: Are you sending a signed APK via Email?

Comment: @RakshitNawani Yes, it is a signed APK.

Comment: Could you please answer my first comment? Your answer doesn't adress my question.

Comment: @S.Czop sorry. Yes, we can install it without any problem via Play Store and this problem happen when downloading the APK from somewhere else.

Comment: Therefore my answer is complete and adresses the post question. Installing applications on Android from somewhere other than Play Store will trigger the warning. There is no way to bypass this warning, since it is built-in to Android itself, and you have no access to the people's phones.

Answer (score 2):

This is not an error but rather a warning. Android has a built-in algorithm to recognize whenever you install something from outside Play Store. You can't make it so that your App doesn't trigger such warning in ANY phone. However, you can go to the settings of any android phone and deactivate the origin revision. Depending on the Android version, you will find it in a different path. You should google for "How to Install from Unknown Sources Android". Follow the instructions and this alert won't show up again.

Comment: We have this issue for publishing our app from other stores too, and we cannot deactivate all users origin revision